# "Sign up" vs. "signup"

Tags: orthography, spacing

When we have a button on a website for creating an account, should it say "sign up" or "signup"?

I see "sign up" in most places, but which is the correct one?

Comment: I have never seen 'signup'; could you provide a link to a place where it appears?

Comment: I really meant 'sign up', fixed it.

Comment: See also: http://notaverb.com/signup

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It should be **sign up**, as that is the [verb form](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sign) (see definition 30).  *[Signup](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/signup)* (or *sign-up*) is a noun.

That pattern usually holds: *log in* (verb) vs. *login* (noun), *sit up* (verb) vs. *situp* (noun), etc.

Comment: Sounds legit :)

Comment: or maybe _leg it_ :D

Comment: @Lipis :D Nice try :)

Comment: @Lipis just created an account only to give you an upvote lol

Comment: It depends on how the other buttons on that page are labeled. If they are all phrased as verbs, use "sign up". If they are nouns, use "signup". As a noun, it can be construed as "pressing this button gets you to the signup page".

Comment: Another illustrative example is "Checkout", meaning "proceed to the CHECKOUT screen" or "initiate a process called CHECKOUT".  "Checkout" is fine by itself, but wrong if next to a button that offers the alternative "Continue Shopping".  In that case, for consistency, the button should say "Check Out" (or{Go|Proceed} to Checkout).