# Sign In "to" or Sign In "with" the website

Tags: grammaticality, programming

I'm working on a "Forgot Password" text and don't know which one is correct:

To reset your password, enter the email address you use to Sign In **to** (website name)

or

To reset your password, enter the email address you use to Sign In **with** (website name)

Comment: Why not check what other websites use?

Comment: Also see  [1](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5302)  [2](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/71930)   [3](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2002)  [4](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80862)  [5](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33845)  [6](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92962) under LINKED heading in right sidebar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, you sign in **to** a website **with** your user name and password.

If you and a friend were to sign in together, you would sign in **with** your friend, but since the website is what you are signing in **to**, not with, the first of your examples is correct.